# Understanding sys.float_info for maximum floats in python

Tags: python, floating-point, precision

I'm trying to understand the information given by `sys.float_info` to understand what the maximum floats in Python are. On my computer, this gives me the following:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.float_info
sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308, min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)
```

The docs give the following example (https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.float_info):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.float_info.dig
15
>>> s = '3.14159265358979'    # decimal string with 15 significant digits
>>> format(float(s), '.15g')  # convert to float and back -> same value
'3.14159265358979'
>>> s = '9876543211234567'    # 16 significant digits is too many!
>>> format(float(s), '.16g')  # conversion changes value
'9876543211234568'
```

However, the following example works just fine for me, even though it also has 16 significant digits (?):

```
>>> s = '.9876543211234567' 
>>> format(float(s), '.16g')
'0.9876543211234567'
```

Also, `sys.float_info.min` yields `2.2250738585072014e-308` which is is obviously a lot smaller and also has 17 significant digits, if I'm correct? How does that work when `sys.float_info.dig = 15`? Am I confusing something here?

How does `sys.float_info.dig = 15` relate to the attributes `sys.float_info.mant_dig` and `sys.float_info.radix`? As far as I understand, if I were to represent some decimal number as a base-2 number (since `sys.float_info.radix = 2`), does `sys.float_info.mant_dig` then give me the maximum integer of the mantissa?

Sorry if I'm confusing some things, maybe I'm not firm enough the mathematical basics here. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> However, the following example works just fine for me, even though it also has 16 significant digits (?):

The documentation says “If X, then Y,” where X is:

- A decimal numeral with up to 15 significant digits is converted to your Python implementation’s float and back to the nearest decimal numeral with at most 15 significant digits.

and Y is:

- The number represented by the original numeral equals the resulting numeral.

That says only what happens if X is true. It does not say what happens if X is false. You have given us a situation where Y is true (you got back the original number) and complained that X is false. That is consistent with the documentation.

> Also, sys.float_info.min yields 2.2250738585072014e-308 which is is obviously a lot smaller and also has 17 significant digits, if I'm correct? How does that work when sys.float_info.dig = 15? Am I confusing something here?

Every floating-point datum other than a NaN (Not a Number) represents one number exactly. It is exactly that number, regardless of how many decimal digits are required to express that number. `sys_float_info.dig` tells you a property about how *fine* the floating-point representation is. It tells you the floating-point representation is so fine, meaning that the numbers it does represent are so close together, that they can be used to distinguish between 15-digit decimal numerals. That just tells you how close the representable numbers are to each other. It does not tell you how many decimal digits it takes to exactly express any of those numbers.

In fact, the smallest positive number representable in your Python implementation’s floating-point format is 2<sup>−1074</sup>, which is 4.940656458412465441765687928682213723650598026143247644255856825006755072702087518652998363616359923797965646954457177309266567103559397963987747960107818781263007131903114045278458171678489821036887186360569987307230500063874091535649843873124733972731696151400317153853980741262385655911710266585566867681870395603106249319452715914924553293054565444011274801297099995419319894090804165633245247571478690147267801593552386115501348035264934720193790268107107491703332226844753335720832431936092382893458368060106011506169809753078342277318329247904982524730776375927247874656084778203734469699533647017972677717585125660551199131504891101451037862738167250955837389733598993664809941164205702637090279242767544565229087538682506419718265533447265625•10<sup>−324</sup>.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I didn't understand what you said: that `dig` "tells you the floating-point representation is so fine, meaning that the numbers it does represent are so close together, that they can be used to distinguish between 15-digit decimal numerals." So two floats can be safely distinguished up to the 15th decimal digit? If so, I still don't get how floats can represent numbers with many more decimal digits (as the smallest positive number)

Comment: @marialagorda: Suppose a straight road is marked with signs every kilometer, and also every hundred meters and every ten meters and every meter. It is also marked with signs every mile. A friend wants to tell you there is a great restaurant on the road, and you want to find which meter marker it is nearest, but the friend only tells you the nearest mile marker, which is mile 2. Which meter marker is it nearest? You cannot know, because, if the restaurant is anywhere from 2.41 kilometers (1.5 miles) to 4.02 kilometers along the road, the nearest mile marker is mile 2…

Comment: … So you cannot convert a four-digit metric measurement to a one-digit English-mile measurement and back and expect to get the same number. If, in addition to mile markers, markers are added for, say, yards and feet, then you can. It is the same with binary and decimal numbers. The places where the binary numerals land on the real number line must be closer together than the decimal numbers you want to convert to binary and back. Otherwise, they do not have enough resolution to retain the necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn more about the specifics of floats for your runtime environment, by checking the value of sys.float_info. This will also tell you what's the largest and smallest number that can be represented with them.

Comment: The question is "I am not sure how to interpret the values  returned by float_info" and your answer is "use float_info". What's the point?